# Why does ViewPager preserve it's current page even new a instance have been created?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**My Context**

Assume i have a `Fragment` contain a `ViewPager` which have 3 pages(fragment). My **onCreateView** method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tv_fragment, null);
        listFragment = new ArrayList<>();
        listFragment.add(new EventFragment());
        listFragment.add(new ChannelFragment());
        listFragment.add(new FavoriteFragment());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        fragmentPagerAdapter = new MainLiveTVtAdapter(
                getChildFragmentManager(), listFragment);

        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        // Center the tabs in the layout
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(null);
        try {
            viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar_bg);
            }
        });
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

I called `viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false);` to set the current page of `ViewPager`, assume `page = 1` mean the second page. When fragment is rendered in window, the second page is shown up, i scroll `ViewPager` to third page then replace this fragment by another one. After that i recreate this fragment and bring it on, but the `ViewPager` still shown the third page even `viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false);` was called with `page = 1`.

As you can see above, `ViewPager` have been created new instance and the `Adapter` is also.

**Can anyone explain why it happen? And how can i fix it?**

**EDIT**

There is my `Adapter` for `ViewPager`

```
public class MainLiveTVtAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private String[] title = {"Sự kiện", "Kênh","Yêu thích"};
    FragmentManager fm;
    public MainLiveTVtAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm=fm;
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return title[position];
    }

//    @Override
//    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
//        if (position >= getCount()) fm.beginTransaction().remove((Fragment) object).commit();
//    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code for `MainLiveTVtAdapter`

Comment: @mr.icetea what do you mean by doesn't preserve it's state?

Comment: Check out : http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/

Comment: Try to create instance of each fragment in getItem() base on position instead of getting from list.

Comment: This: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` is why the ViewPager is retaining the instances.

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) says:  
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the > current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this > limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how platform is designed. It tries to keep state of views which have ids when activity/fragment is recreated. ViewPager's position is kept the same way EditText's content is. 
If you want to get rid of this - there are few ways:

- override onSaveInstanceState and call viewPager.setCurrentItem() with index of your choice,
- override onSaveInstanceState and call viewPager.setAdapter(null),
- override onRestoreInstanceState and call viewPager.setCurrentItem() with index of your choice

There are probably other ways too but usually devs are fine with default behavior which preserves state.

Please note that current item will be the one you set in onCreate if fragment/activity is freshly added and not recreated (savedInstanceState equal to null).

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState ` was not called when i replaced it with another fragment. And there is no `onRestoreInstanceState ` in a fragment :(

Comment: I found `onDestroyView` method which was called when fragments replaced. I put `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` inside this method and before `super call` but it still didn't work.

Comment: In `onCreateView `add:
`setRetainInstance(false);`

and instead of `onRestoreInstanceState` use:
`onActivityCreated()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any dynamic stuff with your pageradapter, you have to implement it like this: [Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager/15261142#15261142)
Otherwise it will behave strangely.

Answer (score 0):

This: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` is why the ViewPager is retaining the instances. The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) says:

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.